# .htaccess Remove first php url parameter if second exist

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

This is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/([^/]+))? pages.php?PAGE=$1&LINK=$3 [L]
```

*where $1 = profile and $3 = john-smith

This is works fine rewriting like *https://example.com/profile/john-smith* but I need a second rewrite rule like *https://example.com/john-smith* only if the second parameter that contains ***john-smith*** exist.

Thank you!

**PS. (Extra rules I have above in my .htaccess file)**

```
# protect files beginning with .
RewriteRule /\.(.*) - [NC,F]

# redirect HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

# No root access without index.* and other security
RewriteEngine On
Options All -Indexes
RewriteBase /
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/pages.php?PAGE=404

# Prevent upload malicious PHP files
<FilesMatch “\.(php|php\.)$”> 
Order Allow,Deny 
Deny from all 
</FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following. Written with shown samples/attempts. Please make sure your htaccess Rules file is present along with pages.php file.

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options All -Indexes -Multiviews
RewriteBase /

# protect files beginning with .
RewriteRule ^\. - [NC,F]

# redirect HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

##Rules for uri https://example.com/john-smith goes from here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ pages.php?PAGE=$1 [QSA,L]

##Rules for uri https://example.com/profile/john-smith goes from here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ pages.php?PAGE=$1&LINK=$2 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]

# No root access without index.* and other security
# Prevent upload malicious PHP files
<FilesMatch "\.(php|php\.)$"> 
Order Allow,Deny 
Deny from all 
</FilesMatch>

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/pages.php?PAGE=404
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Unfortunelly, your solution for  getting https://example.com/john-smith doesn't work.

Comment: @Adrian, so link `example.com/john-smith` should be served by `pages.php?PAGE=$1` correct? Please confirm once.

Comment: Nope. The value (eg. john-smith) comes from LINK parameter

Comment: @Adrian, No, I wanted to confirm that you are hitting link `https://example.com/john-smith` in browser and its getting rewritten(served in backend by page.php`? Could you please confirm once?

Comment: Yes, the url it's rewrited as I want in the browser address field but the page doesn't load the right content.

Comment: @Adrian, these rules should work fine then. Could you please do let me know 2 things, 1st- if you have cleared cache before testing your URLs? 2nd- Do you have any other rules apart from mine posted ones too? Please confirm once.

Comment: Yes, I cleared the cache. And for the second question, yes I have some other rules above.  I will put these in the bottom of my question.

Comment: @Adrian, No, could you please put these at top of your htaccess file and keep already existing below these, then let me know. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: I just tried to move on top and still doesn't work. PS. I just updated my question with all my extra rules from my .htaccess file.

Comment: @Adrian, could you please make sure that your htaccess file and page.php files are in same folder? Because these rules are working fine for my local apache.

Comment: Yes, it is in the same folder.

Comment: @Adrian, I have edited Rules now, please used these rules. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Now all my website pages, event index.php shows 404 error.

Comment: @Adrian, ok, please try commenting `ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/pages.php?PAGE=404` once and try again, let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Adrian, I just moved 2 rules `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/pages.php?PAGE=404` at bottom of htaccess file, you can try commenting them first if that works then we will see it further.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. I just undo my code as your first version and now I don't have 404 error. 
I could have an explanation for why the page does not display content. Inside the pages.php file I also have some includes. Could it affect in any way? Can the path of php includes changes the result of htaccess url rewritte?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235753/discussion-between-adrian-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @Adrian, sorry I can't join room, let us discuss in comments itself.